# How to return the full path of the SaveFileDialog?

Tags: c#, wpf

How to get the full path string from a SaveFileDialog? `SaveFileDialog.FileName` only gives me the filename with extension. I have looked into `SaveFileDialog` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653573.aspx), but I don't see any property does that.

I need to return "C:\Folder1\subFolder2\File004.sdf" not just "File004.sf"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Gets or sets a string containing the full path of the file selected in a file dialog." is what the MSDN article you linked says for `FileName` property. Plus, `FileName` has always given me the full file path.

Answer (score 9):

What I basically do is more or less

```
SaveFileDialog x = new SaveFileDialog();

if (x.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //Use here x.FileName
}
```

and it always returned the full path. Are you sure you don't see the absolute path?

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be using the wrong dll - `win32` instead of `WinForms`. Had the same issue today.

Comment: At least in WPF, the `Microsoft.Win32` version of `dlg.FileName` gives the whole absolute path.

Answer (score -1):

You must catch it after you press "Ok", not before.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?